# How to get @yahoo.nl instead of @yahoo.com?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have a Twitter and recently Twitter asked me to reset my password, my email was a Yahoo mail that ended with **.nl**

It was fake, and so I have to make an account now. However, Yahoo keeps on showing only **.com** on their website. Is there a way I can make a yahoo account with **nl** after the dot?

Comment: Welcome. It looks that you are asking how to create an email address with yahoo.nl.

Answer (score 1):

If the e-mail service provider is not providing you with top-level domain (TLD) options of your choice (.nl) then it is not possible create an account with the said TLD, or any other TLD for that matter.